# com.android.volly.AuthFailureError in making basic volly POST request to a django server

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I am trying to connect to a django server from my android application. I am trying to access my api, making a `POST` request with volly. Everything is set. All the params and headers required, but still I get this error.

```
log: [490] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for https://example.com/
```

It's not letting me access my django Api. It works fine with the PHP server.

```
    public void vollyRequest()
    {
        RequestQueue queue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest request =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST  , "https://example.com/", new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESPONSE: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username","***");
                params.put("password","***");
                return params;
                }
//            @Override
//            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
//            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
//            params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
//            return params;
//            }
        };
        queue.add(request);
    }
```

Comment: I have same error with Php server

Comment: @CodeWarrior did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 12):

**i solved it my self...
This code will get you an auth-token, with the username and password you provide, and then that token will be put in the header to get data from the server...**

```
public void vollyRequestGetAuthToken()
{
    RequestQueue queue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest request =  new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST  , "https://example.com/get-auth-token/", new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override

    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "RESPONSE: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
        System.out.println("RESPONSE:          >>> " + response + "<<<");
    }
}, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ERROR: " + error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
    }
}) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("username","*****");
        params.put("password","*****");
        return params;
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("Authorization",
                String.format("Basic %s", Base64.encodeToString(
                        String.format("%s:%s", "<username>", "<password>").getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT)));
        params.put("username" , "*****" );
        params.put("password" , "*****" );
        return params;
    }
};
    queue.add(request);
}
```

**and now when you have the auth-token, use the following code to send auth-token to get data**

```
@Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
                headers.put("Authorization", "Token <token>");
                return headers;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused when the request is declined/blocked from the API End Point.
The reason could be a malformed request for that,

- Check your request type [GET/POST/ANY OTHER]
- Check the request Header and Body